# Extract elements from the name of an object

Tags: r

I have an object name

```
Test12<-c(8,7,4,3,5,67,3,9,6,6,56,742,23,12,45,56)
```

I would like to extract the last two numbers from the objects name or from Test12 to obtain the numbers 1 and 2 separatedly and place them into two objects.

```
a<- 1
b<- 2
```

I have tried with

```
x <- name(Test12)

substrRight <- function(x, n){
substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}
substrRight(x, 2)
[1] "8"  "7"  "4"  "3"  "5"  "67" "3"  "9"  "6"  "6"  "56" "42" "23" "12" "45" "56"
```

However I get the last 2 ítems of each of the objects elements.

Any help welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nm <- bquote(Test12)` or
`nm <- quote(Test12)` or
`nm <- "Test12"` or
`nm <- deparse(substitute(Test12))` as per answer of @Al.Sal

Will work, then:

```
a <- substr(nm, nchar(nm)-1, nchar(nm)-1)
b <- substr(nm, nchar(nm), nchar(nm))
> a
[1] "1"
> b
[1] "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
    substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

var.name <- deparse(substitute(test12))
var.nums <- substrRight(var.name, 2) 
var.nums <- strsplit(var.nums, "")
var.nums <- unlist(var.nums)
var.nums <- as.vector(as.numeric(var.nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try

```
 library(stringr)
 list2env(setNames(
        as.list(str_extract_all(deparse(substitute(Test12)),
                        perl("\\d(?=\\b$)|\\d(?=[0-9]$)"))[[1]]),
                       letters[1:2]),
                              envir=.GlobalEnv)

   a
  #[1] "1"
    b
  #[1] "2"
```

#### Explanation

```
 deparse(substitute(Test12)) #gets the name of the object
 #[1] "Test12"
```

Regex `"\\d(?=\\b$)` match a digit `lookahead` for word boundary at the end of string `|` or `\\d(?=[0-9]$)")` a digit and `lookahead` for another digit at the end of string.

Suppose your string is:

```
 T95es34t12 <- 1:5
  str_extract_all(deparse(substitute(T95es34t12)),  perl("\\d(?=\\b$)|\\d(?=[0-9]$)"))[[1]]
 #[1] "1" "2"
```

`as.list` creates a list,then name the elements of list with `a`, `b` using `setNames` and use `list2env` to assign the name of the list elements to the list values.